# Derivation of impedance matching formula

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves, electrical-resistance

When matching impedances with a quarter wavelength coupler, how do I derive that its impedance has to be

$$
Z_2=\sqrt{Z_1 Z_3}
$$

where $Z_1,Z_3$ are the impedances of the adjacent materials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume plane waves. The tangential boundary conditions show that the transverse electric and magnetic field vectors must stay in the same direction on transmission or reflexion from the interfaces, assumed aligned with the wavefronts.

Since we know the direction of the waves, let's say the $\vec{E}$ fields are all in the $\hat{X}$ direction, the magnetic fields all in the $\hat{Y}$. By convention, let all  $\vec{E}$ fields point in the +X direction: the amplitude will be negative if this needs to change. Then, if a forward travelling wave has an E field of $+E\, \hat{X}$, the magnetic field will be $+E \,\hat{Y}/\mathcal{Z}$, where $\mathcal{Z}$ is the characteristic impedance of the medium in question. If the wave is propagating in the opposite direction, as the reflected waves will be, an electric field of $+E \,\hat{X}$ corresponds to a magnetic field of $-E\,\hat{Y}/\mathcal{Z}$.

So let the incident wave on the have complex amplitude 1. Then the incident magnetic field is $1/\mathcal{Z}_1$. There will also be a reflected electric field $E_r\,\hat{X}$, which we must solve for. The reflected magnetic field will thus be $-E_r\,\hat{Y}/\mathcal{Z}_1$; the negative sign because of the right hand rule relationship between propagation direction, electric field and magnetic field.

In the layer, there is a forward travelling wave with electric amplitude field $E^+$ and a backwards wave with electric amplitude field $E^-$, both of which you must solve for. The corresponding magnetic fields are $+E^+\,\hat{Y}/\mathcal{Z}_2$ and $-E^-\,\hat{Y}/\mathcal{Z}_2$, again taking proper heed of the sign for the direction of each wave. Then, at the first boundary, a statement of the boundary conditions is:

$$E^+ + E^- = 1$$
$$\frac{1}{\mathcal{Z}_2}\left(E^+-E^-\right) = -\frac{1}{\mathcal{Z}_1}E_r\,\hat{Y}\tag{1}$$

Now let the layer thickness be $\ell$ and the wavenumber be $k$. The layer electric fields are $E^+\,e^{i\,k\,\ell}\,\hat{X}$ and $E^-\,e^{-i\,k\,\ell}\,\hat{X}$ for forward and backwards waves, respectively (note the sign of the phase). The magnetic fields will be $+E^+\,e^{i\,k\,\ell}\,\hat{Y}/\mathcal{z}_2$ and $-E^-\,e^{-i\,k\,\ell}\,\hat{Y}/\mathcal{z}_2$, respectively.

In the third layer, there is only the transmitted field: $E_t\,\hat{X}$ and $E_t\,\hat{Y}/\mathcal{Z}_3$ for the magnetic field.

So the tangential electromagnetic boundary conditions at the second layer are therefore:

$$E^+\,e^{i\,k\,\ell} + E^-\,e^{-i\,k\,\ell} = E_t$$
$$\frac{1}{\mathcal{Z}_2}\left(E^+\,e^{i\,k\,\ell} - E^-\,e^{-i\,k\,\ell}\right) = \frac{1}{\mathcal{Z}_3}\,E_t\tag{2}$$

You can now eliminate $E_t,\,E^+,\,E^-$ from the system (1) and (2) to get an expression for the complex reflexion co-efficient $E_r$. You will find that this implies a condition on the layer thickness as well as the characteristic impedance relationship you cite if you want $E_r=0$.